# Firebase functions logs error working with Cloud Firestore and Node JS

Tags: node.js, function, firebase, cloud, google-cloud-firestore

The Firebase functions by Nodejs is not retrieving the results from the data stored in the Cloud Firestore Database. Giving a:

> TypeError of Undefined user_id

**NodeJS Code**

```
'use-strict'

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document("Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}").onWrite(event => {

const user_id = event.params.user_id;
const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

console.console.log("User ID: " + user_id + " | Notification ID: " + notification_id);
});
```

**Error in Logs of Firebase Functions**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_id' of undefined at 
exports.sendNotification.functions.firestore.document.onWrite.event 
(/user_code/index.js:10:33) at Object.<anonymous> 
(/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:112:27) 
at next (native) at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud- 
functions.js:28:71 at __awaiter (/user_code/node_modules/firebase- 
functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:24:12) at cloudFunction 
(/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:82:36) at 
/var/tmp/worker/worker.js:700:26 at process._tickDomainCallback 
(internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

**Database Rules**

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
match /{document=**} {
allow read, write: if true; } } }
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using version 1.0 of the firebase-functions module in your Cloud Functions code.  The API has changed in 1.0.  Please [consult the migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff) to understand what changed in 1.0.

There is no longer a `params` property on the first argument passed to the the callback for an onWrite trigger.  It was [split into two arguments](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database), a Change, and an EventContext object.  The EventContext argument has a [params](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.EventContext#params) property you should use now.